# Graph only shows the data in 1 graph but not the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm having trouble with my code. It's only showing the data for one graph and the other graph is blank. I can't figure why it's not working.
I'm using the `subplot()` function and my guess is that the the reason might be the way my function are formatted.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvxopt as opt
from cvxopt import blas, solvers
import pandas as pd
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins

np.random.seed(123)
solvers.options['show_progress'] = False

n_assets = 4

n_obs = 1000  # original 1000

return_vec = np.random.randn(n_assets, n_obs)

def rand_weights(n):
    k = np.random.rand(n)
    return k / sum(k) print(rand_weights(n_assets)) print(rand_weights(n_assets))

def random_portfolio(returns):
    p = np.asmatrix(np.mean(returns,axis=1))
    w = np.asmatrix(rand_weights(returns.shape[0]))
    C = np.asmatrix(np.cov(returns))

    mu = w * p.T
    sigma = np.sqrt(w * C * w.T)

    #this recursion reduces outlier to keep the graph nice
    if sigma > 2:
      return random_portfolio(returns)
    return mu, sigma

n_portfolios = 500

means, stds = np.column_stack([random_portfolio(return_vec) for _ in range(n_portfolios)])


plt.plot(return_vec.T, alpha=.4); 
plt.xlabel('time') 
plt.ylabel('returns') 
plt.figure(1) 
plt.subplot(212)

plt.plot(stds, means, 'o', markersize = 5) 
plt.xlabel('std') 
plt.ylabel('mean') 
plt.title('Mean and standard deviation of returns of randomly generated portfolios') 
plt.subplot(211) 
plt.figure(1)

plt.show()
```

[image: my graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the line `plt.subplot(211)` before your first call to `plt.plot`. This is because calls to `plt.subplot` must precede the actual plotting in that subplot.

Comment: That worked like a charm, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!!

Comment: If it worked, you should probably accept the answer.